# App appearing on the taskbar, but without any panel

Tags: 16.04

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. For a few days, my apps are not responding properly. When I try to launch from the search menu or try to open a file, then the icon appears on the taskbar but without any panel. When I installed the zoom app it worked properly. However, for the Telegram app, no panel is appearing except the icon on the sidebar.

In the image, you can see the telegram icon at the bottom of the sidebar. However, the app is not showing any panel.
If anyone knows how to fix it, then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

[image]